# How to extract two variables from this string in PHP

Tags: php, extract

I have a string like this :

```
oauth_token=1%2F7VDUGD4tKIqSu4jX4DoeCRD1KbqqgTxFnFFliVgbSss&oauth_token_secret=Rk%2FwejMIg6t%2BFphvRd%2BZ5Wkc
```

How can I extract the two variables `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` from the about string using PHP

NOTE: this is not coming from the URL( we can do that using `$_GET`)

Thank YOU

Comment: Are you talking about doing something like substr(myString, strpos(mystring, "="), strpos(mystring, "&") - strpos(mystring, "="))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) for parsing query string parameters.

```
// Extract into current scope, access as if they were PHP variables
parse_str($str);
echo $oauth_token;
echo $oauth_token_secret;

// Extract into array
parse_str($str, $params);
echo $params['oauth_token'];
echo $params['oauth_token_secret'];
```

You may wish to `urldecode()` the variables after you've extracted them.

Comment: This looks very simple, but not displaying anything ... could you correct it. Thank You

Comment: @KillerFish: It outputs both variables for me.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$text = "oauth_token=1%2F7VDUGD4tKIqSu4jX4DoeCRD1KbqqgTxFnFFliVgbSss&oauth_token_secret=Rk%2FwejMIg6t%2BFphvRd%2BZ5Wkc"
;
$i=explode('&',$text);
$j=explode('=',$i[0]);
$k=explode('=',$i[1]);
echo $j[0]."<br>";
echo $j[1]."<br>";
echo $k[0]."<br>";
echo $k[1]."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

1, split the two parts of the $string,

```
$str_array = explode('&',$string);
```

2, get the part after the "=" sign, so for the oauth_token part:

```
 $oauth_token_array = explode('=',$str_array[0]);
 $oauth_token = $oauth_token_array[1];
```

EDIT: ignore this, it's definitely verbose. BoltClock's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best way (most reusable) is to use a function which returns an array similar to $_GET.

**edit** There is already a function for this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php This will work with array get values too.

$values = array();
parse_str($query_strng, $values);

Quite an ugly function, why can't it just return the array of values. It either stuffs them into individual variables or you need to pass in a reference. Come on php, you can do better. /rant

Comment: Haha, I've always hated that inconsistency in array functions.